# Xaml with shared projects: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Xaml with Forms in a shared project, so I was using the xaml [code example for ListView using Xaml here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/deepdive).

This is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

As, you can see, I haven't changed much.  Here's the [sample code on xamarin's github repo using PCL](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/commit/94cbeb7fdb7ab3e7281242aa1cb90b52d8d37e5c).

I'm getting the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'XamarinFormsXamlSample' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[image: Could not load file or assembly 'XamarinFormsXamlSample' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this error?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your solution? I'm not seeing this error when I compile/run XamarinFormsXamlSample...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to you iOS property settings and change the Assembly name from XamarinFormsXamlSampleiOS to XamarinFormsXamlSample, that should solve your problem, this only happens with shared projects.